# Take Post ID from one loop and exclude that post from the other loop

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type

I am trying to exclude the post from the second loop which are already shown in the first one.

I have a page template created to display newest one Custom Post named "inspirations".

I created a widget to display the other posts from the same post type and used that widget on the page template I created.

Here is the code of the Page Template:

```
<?php
/**
 * Template Name: Inspiratie
 *
 * A custom page template without sidebar.
 *
 * The "Template Name:" bit above allows this to be selectable
 * from a dropdown menu on the edit page screen.
 */
get_header(); ?>
<div id="container" class="seprator">
  <div id="content" class="inspiratie-area" role="main">
    <?php $inspiratiepage_query = new WP_Query('showposts=1&post_type=inspirations');  ?>
    <?php while ($inspiratiepage_query->have_posts()) : $inspiratiepage_query->the_post(); ?>
    <div class="inspiratie-box" id="inspiratie-<?php the_ID(); ?>">
      <h2 class="entry-title orange">
        <?php the_title(); ?>
      </h2>
      <?php the_content() ?>
      <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
    <?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>
  </div>
</div>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

below is the code of my widget I created:

```
class Meer_Inspiratie extends WP_Widget {
    function Meer_Inspiratie() {
        $widget_ops = array('classname' => 'Meer_Inspiratie', 'description' => 'Display Inspiratie Posts' );
        $this->WP_Widget('Meer_Inspiratie', 'Inspiratie Post Widget', $widget_ops);
    }

    function widget($args, $instance) {
        extract($args, EXTR_SKIP);

        echo $before_widget;
        $title = $instance['title'];
        $items = $instance['items'];

        if(!empty($title))
        {
            echo $before_title;
                echo $title;
            echo $after_title;
        }

        if(!empty($items))
        { ?>
            <?php 

            $inspiratie_query = new WP_Query(   array(
                                    'post_type' => 'inspirations',
                                    'posts_per_page' =>  $items,
                                  'post__not_in'   => array(1),
                                    )
                                );  ?>

            <?php while ($inspiratie_query->have_posts()) : $inspiratie_query->the_post(); ?>
                <div class="inspiratie_query">
                    <p class="inspiratie_txt"><?php the_excerpt() ?></p>
                    <div class="inspiratie_img">
                        <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { the_post_thumbnail('inspiratie-product-thumb');}?>
                    </div>
                    <div class="inspiratie_quote">
                        <?php
                            echo '<blockquote class="inspiratie-quote">';
                            echo get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'my_specs_box_quote', true );
                            echo '</blockquote>';
                        ?>
                    </div>
                    <div class="clear"></div>
                    <a class="more-post" href="<?php the_permalink()?>">Lees meer</a>
                </div>

            <?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>

        <?php }

        echo $after_widget;
    }

    function update($new_instance, $old_instance) {
        $instance = $old_instance;
        $instance['items'] = strip_tags($new_instance['items']);
        $instance['title'] = $new_instance['title'];

        return $instance;
    }

    function form($instance) {
        $instance = wp_parse_args( (array) $instance, array( 'items' => '', 'title' => '') );
        $items = strip_tags($instance['items']);
        $title = $instance['title'];

?>      
            <p><label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('title'); ?>">Title: <input class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('title'); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('title'); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo esc_attr($title); ?>" /></label></p>

            <p><label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('items'); ?>">No. of Items: <input class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('items'); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('items'); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo esc_attr($items); ?>" /></label></p>

<?php
    }
}

register_widget('Meer_Inspiratie');

/**
*   End Inspiratie Post Widget
**/
```

I am trying to exclude the post I have currently in my content area from the widget..

Thank in advance....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

dnt know where your sidebar widget is calling from in your template page but it its call below the first loop of your post where you are pulling 1 post dden have a try something like this

```
<?php 
$not_id=get_the_ID();
            $inspiratie_query = new WP_Query(   array(
                                    'post_type' => 'inspirations',
                                    'posts_per_page' =>  $items,
                                  'post__not_in'   => array($not_id),
                                    )
                                );  ?>
```

havent check the code. hope this work for you

Comment: I have called up sidebar under the page template which I forget to include in the code....

Comment: actually the idea was to get the id of the post that you are looping in your template file.get_the_ID() which returns the above post id if it was not your widget. so assumed that it still loops that id for the widget. have you tried this ?

Comment: i have tried this but no benefits...
here is the link for your reference: http://onesmartcontrol.com/dev/inspiratie/

Comment: i change the query name and tried your method and this time it works..
thanks a lot...